# Развертывание Rails приложения на хостинге

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как развернуть Rails приложение на VPS сервере? Нужно ли что-то дополнительно устанавливать на сервере, кроме самого Rails?

Что было сделано:

- Установлен Rails на VPS
- Загружено на сервер нужное rails приложение
- После чего через консоль запустил само приложение `cd appname` , `rails s`

Как получить к нему доступ из вне? То есть через URL или IP адрес в браузере?

Comment: Попробовали? Заработало?

Comment: Я установил Rails на VPS сервер, залил туда свое приложение. Через консоль запустил его. В консоли написало что запущен localhost:3000. А вот как действовать дальше к сожалению не знаю

Comment: Ну, формально это всё, на 3000-ном порте работает ваше приложение. Если вас интересует что-то конкретное, об этом и спрашивайте :)

Comment: @D-side вопрос дополнил, пожалуйста посмотрите

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В последних версиях Rails, где-то около 4.0 и выше — **никак**, потому что вебсервер вешается по умолчанию на `localhost:3000` и принимает соединения только через ["локальную петлю"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), от самого себя к самому себе. Для нужд разработки этого достаточно, да и в production-средах в большинстве случаев тоже (из-за балансировщика нагрузки; но тоже не всегда).

<sub>Надеюсь, вы уже заменили Webrick на что-то более серьёзное. Webrick написан на чистом Ruby и работает одним процессом в один поток. Он даже одного пользователя будет выдерживать с трудом.</sub>

Как правило, **сервер приложения**, запускаемый таким образом, не приспособлен для работы "лицом в интернет" (неэффективен, мало возможностей настройки), поэтому его разворачивают за **прозрачным прокси** (обычно `nginx`), который принимает соединения напрямую и **обслуживает самостоятельно запросы на статические файлы**, а остальное перенаправляет к **серверу приложения**.

Тема достаточно обширная и гайдов на просторах интернета очень много, очень разного качества, и я не рискну писать ещё один здесь. Я изложу общий план действий, а их конкретную реализацию можно придумать и самостоятельно:

- Заставить **сервер приложения** слушать сетевой адрес/порт, доступный **локально**  (или адрес/порт с ограниченным доступом, или вовсе Unix domain socket)
- Поставить перед сервером приложения балансировщик нагпузки/прозрачный прокси и организовать раздачу статики (что сервер приложения обычно делает неэффективно)

  - Например, поставить `nginx` и сделать ему `try_files` на статику и `proxy_pass` на локальную точку, которую слушает **сервер приложения**
- **Обеспечить выживание**: воспользоваться любым решением, которое будет автоматически запускать приложение при запуске машины (чтобы после перезагрузки приложение запускалось без лишних движений), а также перезапускало его в случае падения.

---

**Но это очень примитивный сценарий, который не для всех приложений подойдёт.** Есть целый род деятельности по планированию и реализации инфраструктуры. Я совершенно никак не затронул:

- Отслеживание признаков жизни сервера
- Сбор ошибок и уведомление о них разработчиков
- Резервные копии
- Процесс автоматического разворачивания

...а это всё весьма нужные вещи.

---

Есть также более весёлые варианты вроде сборки Docker-образа из приложения и запуск его в виде отдельного контейнера. Но итоговая система будет приблизительно такой же. Есть определённая свобода вроде "делать ли `nginx` отдельным контейнером".

Answer (score 1):

В списке установленного ещё забыли сам Ruby) я использую связку apache+passenger для своих приложений. Для passenger очень неплохая документация, если надумаете использовать, только сразу ограничте ему потоки, а то приложение будет падать из за нехватки памяти.